# Delphi - Text in Tray Icon

Tags: windows, delphi, object, pascal, tray

I am trying to write an application that places the current temperature (fetched from an online source) and display the temperature (as text) in the application icon in the system tray/notification (for Windows 7+).

I am using the Delphi TTrayIcon component, and I cannot figure out how to display text in the icon area.  I've had other applications in the past that would do this, so it must be possible.

Comment: You can't display text there. That area displays icons. You can produce an icon, draw the temperature on it, and then update the icon to display your new one that displays the temp.

Comment: like KenWhite said your problem is not how to write text on the tray icon your problem how to change the icon

Comment: I will narrow this problem a bit down. To meet the gudelines, you should provide 16x16 and 32x32 pixel icons. That's because the user can change DPI whilst your app. will be running and if you provide only 16x16, it will be scaled to the bigger size. If you can create such icon "on the fly" without saving to disk might be the question you want to ask.

Comment: @victoria Er, that's not right. The notification icon is a small icon. So you ask the system what the small icons size is. And for sure it can be something between 16 and 32.

Comment: @David, _If only a 16x16 pixel icon is provided, it is scaled to a larger size in a system set to a high dpi value. This can lead to an unattractive result. It is recommended that you provide both a 16x16 pixel icon and a 32x32 icon in your resource file. Use LoadIconMetric to ensure that the correct icon is loaded and scaled appropriately._ ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx)). You should render both sizes.

Comment: @Victoria Yeah, the docs are lousy. Call GetSystemMetrics to find the size of a small icon, and provide an icon of that size. That's how you avoid aliasing.

Comment: Docs discuss graphic icons - which are not produced at runtime. LoadIconMetric can be asked to load a system smallicon sized icon, which will use a larger icon to scale down when an exact size match is not available.

Comment: @David, i see your point now. Is there a way to get notification when the notification area DPI changes then (e.g. if the `WM_DPICHANGED` message is received by the icon message recipient)? I would try it, but have no environment by hand.

Comment: @Victoria with per monitor DPI I would think the icon would need to contain one image for each different monitor DPI. Monitor DPI change notification is the same as for any program.

Comment: @David, yes, if you duplicate screen, then you will need to let the system scale the icon for you (because it's still the same taskbar). If you extend the screen, taskbar will be only on one monitor, so you could be able to prepare the icon of the right size. The point is if you can receive `WM_DPICHANGED` message if the taskbar is on a monitor whose DPI was changed even if your app (only with single, main form) is on a different monitor. Or any other notification, so you can update the icon size. I would ask a question about it (or try it by myself), but I couldn't verify the answer :-(

Comment: @Victoria You can revive notification of all changes to screen DPI. And you can place taskbar on multiple monitors.

Comment: @David, thanks! I know that you can display taskbar on multiple monitors. But it's the same taskbar (only one exists at the time, as far as I know), so you must rely on scaling in that case. If you prepare a single resolution icon e.g. for the primary monitor, say in size 16x16, on secondary monitor you can get crippled result (if the size of the icon there will be e.g. 32x32).

Comment: @Victoria I'd expect that you would supply an icon with multiple images

Answer (score 5):

Notification icons are just that. Icons. They have no means to display text that you provide them. So, to achieve your goals you need to dynamically create an icon that contains text and supply that as the notification icon.

Note that the notification icon is a small icon whose size is given by the [`SM_CXSMICON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385.aspx) system metric.

Comment: Notification icons, i.e. in the taskbar, can very well display a text (a balloon hint), which can be set dynamically, using `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, Data);`, where `Data` is a `PNotifyIconData`.

Comment: @rudy That is not what is being discussed here

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. He wants to do the same as the CoreTemp app on my laptop. They also create icons on the fly and then display them.